# SOLR, how to set allowleadingwildcard in the SOLR UI?

Tags: solr, full-text-search

When trying to do a phrase search like:

```
{!complexphrase inOrder=true}display_name:"j.j. *"
```

I am getting this error:

```
cannot parse 'j.j. *': '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery"
```

The Java API talks about setAllowLeadingWildcard(true), but how do I do this in the solr-ui?

(Trying to add "allowLeadingWildcard=true" to raw query parameters in the ui did not help!)

Comment: Isn't that the same query as `display_name:"j.j."`? The last wild card will be just any term, if any at all.

Comment: @matslindh field display_name might be string field so will not return results starting with j.j.

Comment: @Begzad Did sending this {!complexphrase inOrder=true}display_name:"j.j. *" directly in q not working?

Comment: @AmanTandon In that case there is no need for using the complexphrase query parser, as you can perform a regular wildcard query. The error message also indicates that the `*` has been parsed as a separate token.

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, thanks for the hint, That should work!

Comment: @AmanTandon No, "complexphrase" does not like a "leading wildcard"!
I am getting this error:

    cannot parse 'j.j. *': '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery"

Also, without "complexphrase", SOLR search does not support wildcard in "multi terms", you could use wildcard with single terms, though

Comment: Thanks @BehzadPirvali